# How to find Error and Line number in Log Cat

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I am developing an android app, but I am facing a problem when I try to run it on an emulator.
I've read a few answers from this site but was unable to resolve the problem by myself. My logcat is showing errors but I am unable to find what error it is and where it has occurred.

```
02-27 17:30:34.991: D/AndroidRuntime(2997): Shutting down VM
02-27 17:30:35.011: W/dalvikvm(2997): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mjcet/com.example.mjcet.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at com.example.mjcet.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: *MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)*, don't use findViewById before onCreate is called

Comment: com.example.mjcet.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14) this line have error

Comment: There is some error with findViewById() in your activity. Kindly post the code for MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997): at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):at com.example.mjcet.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
```

From here you will get to know the *error* and *line number* in the `class`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
02-27 17:30:35.061: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at com.example.mjcet.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
```

Here is the problem:

```
at com.example.mjcet.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
```

MainActivity, line 14, null pointer exception

Most likely the view is null that you are trying to find(not in the activity's xml or calling `findViewById` before `onCreate` is called?).